# How to use bluebird .all and .reflect effectively?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have an array of promises which I need to wait till all the promises are fulfilled or rejected.
Here is what i am doing

```
var = [promiseA,promiseB,promiseC]      
    Promise.all(promises.map(function(promise) {      
       return promise.reflect();     
    })).each(function(inspection) {      
    if (inspection.isFulfilled()) {     
    console.log("A promise in the array was fulfilled   with",inspection.value());        
   } else {
       console.error("A promise in the array was 
       rejected with",  inspection.reason());      
    }        
 })
```

The above code prints each promise’s fulfilled or rejected value.In my case each promise here returns a success or error json. I need to get the all the successful json values using a function like .then().

When I try to get values using .then

```
Promise.all(promises.map(function(promise) {       
   return promise.reflect();    
 })).then(data){
//_settledValue gives me the json value either success json or error json
   console.log('data[0]::::’+JSON.stringify(data[0]._settledValue));    
}.
```

How I will ignore the error json and take only success json here?
Can anyone help me to figure this ?

Comment: If the return result of your asynchronous method doesn't really throw an error, but return a string that says that it's an error, you probably have to handle that yourself by checking for that string, as Promises can't read. `Array.filter` comes to mind ?

Comment: [`Promise.filter`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.filter.html)?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Array.filter` or `Bluebird.filter` as others suggested.

```
Bluebird.all(promises.map(function(promise) {           
  return promise.reflect();        
}))
  .filter(function(promise) {return promise.isFulfilled();})
  // or .then(promises => promises.filter(/*...*/))
  .then(function (data) {
     // only successful ones are available here...
  });
```

Comment: But what if you wanted to see all exceptions as well?